# How To Add Multiple Roles Using Rails Form and Role Model Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello i have a Roles app where a user can have multiple roles. I am using Roles Model Gem. As you can see below:

```
4.2.5@2.2.4 (main)> User.valid_roles
=> [
    [0] :admin,
    [1] :report_writer,
    [2] :candidate,
    [3] :client_contact
]
```

I would like a check box form that can select multiple roles for the user. I've been trying for an hour and can't figure it out. Can anyone help?

Here is the form

```
%h1 Edit User

= form_for @user, url: admin_user_path(@user) do |f|

.form-group
  = f.label :first_name
  = f.text_field :first_name

.form-group
  = f.label :last_name
  = f.text_field :last_name

.form-group
  = f.label :email
  = f.text_field :email

.form-group
  = f.label :password
  = f.password_field :password

.form-actions
  = link_to "Cancel", admin_users_path, class: "btn btn-grey"
  = f.submit class: "btn btn-primary pull-right"
```

Answer (score 1):

Haven't used role_model gem, but looking at [docs](https://github.com/martinrehfeld/role_model), the following should work:

```
<%= form_for @user, url: admin_user_path(@user) do |f| %>
  ...
  <div class='form-group'>
    <% User.valid_roles.each do |valid_role| %>
      <div>
        <%= valid_role.humanize %>
        <%= f.check_box :roles, multiple: true, valid_role %>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
  ...
<% end %>
```

After submitting the form, your server should receive the following params (example when checked both 'admin' and 'client_contact'):

```
{
  user: {
    first_name: '...',
    last_name: '...',
    email: '...',
    password: '...',
    roles: [
     'admin',
     'client_contact'
    ]
  }
}
```

Do not forget to include `roles: []` to strong params. Example below:

users_controller.rb

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  ...
end

...

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, roles: [])
end
```